# How I can use Socket method?

Tags: android, sockets, methods, textview, ip-address

I'm beginner for programming in Android. I want use this method:

```
Socket socket;
socket.getInetAddress() ;
```

I would like print in a `TextView` the IP address to which I am connected.
Is this possible? How should I do it?

Thanks!

I tried this, but nothing work

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

  Socket s = new Socket();
  String host ="10.10.20.xxxx";

try {
    s.connect( new InetSocketAddress( host, 6000 ), 1000 );

    InetAddress inetAddress = s.getLocalAddress();
    String ip = inetAddress.getHostAddress();
    //Now, I would like to have printed out the IP-address
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ip , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//But nothing happens
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried?

Comment: Thanks Philippe, for your editing, I updated my question.

Comment: Are you able to make a regular `Toast` message appear?

Comment: Always try the simplest first and build on the results. For example, first try printing "Hello!" in a `Toast`. If that works, then continue with the `Socket` stuff. I put an answer below, but I'm confused why you want to do this, as it looks like you already know the address of the server you're connecting to. (`String host = ....`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the address of the host that a socket is connected to, you should use [`getInetAddress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress%28%29) rather than `getLocalAddress()`. Thus, your code could look like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    Socket s = new Socket();
    String host ="10.10.20.xxxx";

    try {
        s.connect( new InetSocketAddress( host, 6000 ), 1000 );

        InetAddress inetAddress = s.getInetAddress();        // <---- Here!
        String ip = inetAddress.getHostAddress();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ip , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now try this solution, Thanks!

Comment: You may be getting an exception and aren't seeing it (because of the `try...catch`). Try adding `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` to the `catch` to help you debug this.